# Как в Calculate Linux узнать флаги по-умолчанию для бинарного пакета?

Tags: linux

чтобы загрузить его не компилируя при помощи `emerge -1gK sys-devel/binutils` , например для пакета binutils?

Сейчас portage мне пишет

```
masked by: use flag configuration mismatch
```

В ответах посоветовали `equery uses binutils`, но она не рассказывает о бинарниках:

```
[ Legend : U - final flag setting for installation]
[        : I - package is installed with flag     ]
[ Colors : set, unset                             ]
 * Found these USE flags for sys-devel/binutils-2.24-r3:
 U I
 + + cxx         : Build support for C++ (bindings, extra libraries, code generation, ...)
 + + multitarget : Adds support to binutils for cross compiling (does not work with gas)
 + + nls         : Add Native Language Support (using gettext - GNU locale utilities)
 - - static-libs : Build static versions of dynamic libraries as well
 - - test        : Workaround to pull in packages needed to run with FEATURES=test. Portage-2.1.2 handles this internally, so don't set it in make.conf/package.use anymore
 - - vanilla     : Do not add extra patches which change default behaviour; DO NOT USE THIS ON A GLOBAL SCALE as the severity of the meaning changes drastically
 + + zlib        : Add support for zlib (de)compression
```

План такой:

1. посмотреть чему равен PORTAGE_BINHOST
2. получить метаинформацию о пакете с найденного места
3. выяснить какие флаги нужны

1) # grep -r PORTAGE_BINHOST /var/lib/layman | grep CLDX/amd64

```
/var/lib/layman/distros/profiles/CLDX/amd64/make.defaults:#PORTAGE_BINHOST="http://mirror.yandex.ru/calculate/CLDX/grp/x86_64"
/var/lib/layman/distros/profiles/CLDX/amd64/make.defaults:PORTAGE_BINHOST="http://mirror.cnet.kz/calculate/CLDX/grp/x86_64"
```

2) `wget http://mirror.cnet.kz/calculate/CLDX/grp/x86_64/Packages`

3) `grep -B1 -A11 -E 'CPV: sys-devel/binutils-[0-9]' Packages`

Будет выведена метаинформация:

```
BUILD_TIME: 1414973459
CPV: sys-devel/binutils-2.24-r3
DEFINED_PHASES: compile install postinst postrm test unpack
DEPEND: sys-devel/gnuconfig >=sys-devel/binutils-config-3 sys-libs/zlib sys-devel/gettext sys-devel/flex virtual/yacc
DESC: Tools necessary to build programs
IUSE: cxx multislot multitarget nls static-libs test vanilla zlib
KEYWORDS: amd64 x86
LICENSE: || ( GPL-3 LGPL-3 )
MTIME: 1435083762
RDEPEND: >=sys-devel/binutils-config-3 sys-libs/zlib
SIZE: 6839432
USE: abi_x86_64 amd64 cxx elibc_glibc kernel_linux nls userland_GNU zlib
REPO: gentoo
```

Флаги, я думаю, в предпоследней строке (почему я думаю что это флаги, с которыми проводилась сборка? То есть в какой доке это написано? не знаю.)

В моём случае надо было отключить флаги USE="-multitarget -static-libs"

```
[binary   R    ] sys-devel/binutils-2.24-r3::gentoo  USE="cxx nls zlib (-multislot) -multitarget* -static-libs* {-test} -vanilla" 6680 KiB
```

Нет ли какой утилиты по-проще это смотреть?

Answer (score 1):

```
equery uses binutils
```

> Как в Calculate Linux...

[wiki.gentoo.org](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Handbook:Main_Page/ru)

Comment: интересно, но ответ на другой вопрос.

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?

Comment: моё утверждение основано на том, что я спрашиваю про бинарные пакеты, а мне отвечают про пакеты собираемые из исходников

Answer (score 1):

Очень давно не хватало подобной утилиты. Все никак руки не доходили. Наконец собрался и наваял [скриптик](https://gist.github.com/seamus-45/e5a16dadd94c3d3030ad).

Пример работы:

```
❯❯❯ udiff.sh media-sound/clementine
Binary package 'media-sound/clementine' different by these USE flags:
+abi_x86_64
+amd64
+elibc_glibc
-lastfm
+kernel_linux
-mtp
-projectm
-udisks
+userland_GNU
```

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы.

Comment: планируется ли написание пакета для утилиты и пропихивание его в официальное дерево?